# QtCreator intellisense missing when importing js files with Qt.include(...)

Tags: javascript, qt, qt-creator, qml

Qt Creator is a good editor, but sometimes it is very frustrating. The fact is that intellisense does not always work correctly.

**Sample project would look`s like this:**

```
//Test1.js file
function test1() {
   console.log('hi from test1');
}

//Test2.js file
Qt.include('Test1.js');
function test2() {
   console.log('hi from test2');
   test1();  
}

//Test.qml file
import QtQuick 1.1
import "Test2.js" as Test2

QtObject {
    Component.onCompleted: {
         Test2.test1(); //<--- intellisense missing here
         Test2.test2();
    }
}
```

**The trouble:**

[image: intellisense missing]

The editor intellisense  miss the `test1` function included in imported `Test2.js`. The `Qt.include` is simple thing - just say qml compiler - hey, copy and paste this js file content here.

**The questions is**

1. Is any way to fix this QtCreator behavior?
2. Is QtCreator plugin model allow to add this behaviour to existing intellisense code? Or this should be fixed with patching QtCreator code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty patch.

Need to patch 2 files
source\qt-creator\src\libs\qmljs\qmljsdocument.h and qmljsdocument.cpp.
But the function "Follow symbol under cursor" might not work correctly, if the file has Qt.include

```
@@ -104,9 +104,13 @@ public:

 private:
     bool parse_helper(int kind);
+    void parseQtInclude(QString dir, QString fileName, QString& result);
+
+    QList<QString> _parsedFileNames;

 private:
     QmlJS::Engine *_engine;
+    QmlJS::Engine *_codeCompleteEngine;
     AST::Node *_ast;
     Bind *_bind;
     QList<QmlJS::DiagnosticMessage> _diagnosticMessages;


@@ -168,6 +168,7 @@ QList<Language::Enum> Document::companionLanguages(Language::Enum language)

 Document::Document(const QString &fileName, Language::Enum language)
     : _engine(0)
+    , _codeCompleteEngine(0)
     , _ast(0)
     , _bind(0)
     , _fileName(QDir::cleanPath(fileName))
@@ -197,6 +198,9 @@ Document::~Document()

     if (_engine)
         delete _engine;
+
+    if (_codeCompleteEngine)
+        delete _codeCompleteEngine;
 }

 Document::MutablePtr Document::create(const QString &fileName, Language::Enum language)
@@ -337,9 +341,54 @@ public:

 } // anonymous namespace

+void Document::parseQtInclude(QString dir, QString fileName, QString& result)
+{
+
+    QFile file(dir + QDir::separator() + fileName);
+
+    if (_parsedFileNames.contains(file.fileName()) || !file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
+        return;
+    }
+
+    _parsedFileNames.append(file.fileName());
+
+    QFileInfo fileInfo(file);
+    QTextStream in(&file);
+    QString source = QString();
+
+    while(!in.atEnd()) {
+        source += in.read(2048);
+    }
+
+    file.close();
+    source.remove(QLatin1String(".pragma library"));
+
+    int endPos = 0;
+    int pos = source.indexOf(QLatin1String("Qt.include("), endPos);
+
+    while (pos >= 0 && pos + 11 < source.length()) {
+        QChar comma = source.at(pos + 11);
+        endPos = source.indexOf(comma + QLatin1String(")"), pos);
+        if (endPos == -1)
+            return;
+
+        QString fullStaterment = QString(source.begin() + pos, endPos - pos + 2);
+        QString importName = QString(source.begin() + pos + 12, endPos - pos - 12);
+
+        parseQtInclude(fileInfo.absolutePath(), importName, result);
+
+        source.replace(fullStaterment, QString());
+
+        pos = source.indexOf(QLatin1String("Qt.include("));
+    }
+
+    result += source;
+}
+
 bool Document::parse_helper(int startToken)
 {
     Q_ASSERT(! _engine);
+    Q_ASSERT(! _codeCompleteEngine);
     Q_ASSERT(! _ast);
     Q_ASSERT(! _bind);

@@ -349,6 +398,31 @@ bool Document::parse_helper(int startToken)
     Parser parser(_engine);

     QString source = _source;
+    QString fullSource = _source;
+
+    int endPos = 0;
+    int pos = fullSource.indexOf(QLatin1String("Qt.include("), endPos);
+
+    while (pos >= 0 && pos + 11 < fullSource.length()) {
+        QChar comma = fullSource.at(pos + 11);
+        endPos = fullSource.indexOf(comma + QLatin1String(")"), pos);
+        if (endPos == -1)
+            break;
+
+        QString fullStaterment = QString(fullSource.begin() + pos, endPos - pos + 2);
+        QString importName = QString(fullSource.begin() + pos + 12, endPos - pos - 12);
+        QString result = QString();
+
+        parseQtInclude(this->path(), importName, result);
+
+        fullSource.replace(fullStaterment, result);
+
+        pos = fullSource.indexOf(QLatin1String("Qt.include("));
+        if (pos == -1 || pos + 11 == source.length())
+            break;
+        comma = fullSource.at(pos + 11);
+    }
+
     lexer.setCode(source, /*line = */ 1, /*qmlMode = */isQmlLikeLanguage(_language));

     CollectDirectives collectDirectives(path());
@@ -369,9 +443,37 @@ bool Document::parse_helper(int startToken)
     }

     _ast = parser.rootNode();
+    AST::Node *savedAst = _ast;
     _diagnosticMessages = parser.diagnosticMessages();

+    if (endPos > 0) {
+        _codeCompleteEngine = new Engine();
+        Lexer lexerCodeComplete(_codeCompleteEngine);
+        Parser parserCodeComplete(_codeCompleteEngine);
+
+        bool _parsed;
+
+        lexerCodeComplete.setCode(fullSource, /*line = */ 1, /*qmlMode = */isQmlLikeLanguage(_language));
+        switch (startToken) {
+        case QmlJSGrammar::T_FEED_UI_PROGRAM:
+            _parsed = parserCodeComplete.parse();
+            break;
+        case QmlJSGrammar::T_FEED_JS_PROGRAM:
+            _parsed = parserCodeComplete.parseProgram();
+            break;
+        case QmlJSGrammar::T_FEED_JS_EXPRESSION:
+            _parsed = parserCodeComplete.parseExpression();
+            break;
+        default:
+            Q_ASSERT(0);
+        }
+
+        if (_parsed)
+            _ast = parserCodeComplete.rootNode();
+    }
+
     _bind = new Bind(this, &_diagnosticMessages, collectDirectives.isLibrary, collectDirectives.imports);
+    _ast = savedAst;

     return _parsedCorrectly;
 }
```